# jqgrid: how to sort on a different column

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a column "Amount" on the jqGrid. When I click on top of "Amount" column, the grid needs to be sorted by another column called "Amount Payable".

How can I achieve this.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the `onSortCol` function you could test for the column being sorted and then change the value.

Ex.

```
onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortorder) {    
    if(index === "Amount"){
        index = "AmountPayable";              
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't posted the code of jqGrid which you use. What you should try to do as the first is the set `index` property for `Amount` column in the value of name of column which you called as "Amount Payable"`.

Another way would be to use `sorttype` property for `Amount` column defined as function. The way works in case of usage `datatype: "local"` or in case of usage `loadonce: true` option with remote `datatype` ("json", "jsonp" or "xml"). What you need to do is just add `sorttype` property for `Amount` column defined about as following:

```js
{
    name: "Amount",
    sorttype: function (cellValue, rowData) {
        return rowData.AmountPayable; // use the value from another column for
                                      // defining of the position of sorted rows
    }}
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690875/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935) for another code examples.