# jqgrid: Sort based on two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to sort a column in jqgrid by two different columns. For instance, I have a column "StoreName" and its sort will be determined by the columns "d0_key" and "d0_tot_key" (both integers). I understand that sorttype in the colmodel can be use to create a custom sort, but I'm not finding an algorithm that takes into account both columns. Below is a simple representation of the data.

```
StoreName   d0_key  d0_tot_key
92nd Gessner    1   0
92nd Gessner    1   0
Total Sum       1   10
Total Avg       1   20
Annco           2   0
Annco           2   0
Total Sum       2   10
Total Avg       2   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need that sorting by `StoreName` column should by made based on the values from the columns "d0_key" and "d0_tot_key" you should define `sorttype` **as function** in the `StoreName` column. Before sorting by column `StoreName` will be started the `sorttype` column will be called. The value returned by the function will be used *instead of* the value from the `StoreName` column during determine the order or sorted grid. So you can construct some function like `d0_key * 1000 + d0_tot_key` which corresponds your requirements. If I understand you correct then it can be about the following

```js
{
    name: "StoreName",
    sorttype: function (cell, obj) {
        return parseInt(obj.d0_key) * 1000 + parseInt(obj.d0_tot_key);
    },
    ...
}
```

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001822/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690875/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935) provides examples of usage `sorttype` as function. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690875/315935) seems to me mostly close to your requirements.

Comment: This works well, thanks. I'm trying to figure out how I can figure out which column I've clicked to sort while I'm in the sorttype function. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @ThomasMondelli: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. If you includes the function as `sorttype` property of "StoreName" column and if the function is called then the "StoreName" column is clicked. Is your real grid other as the grid which you described?

Answer (score 3):

Version [4.5.0 of the jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) [added multi-sort support](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3achange#jqgrid_4.5.0_changes_and_fixes). You should be able to do something like this:

Just make sure you've turned `multiSort` on:

```
$('#gridId').jqGrid({
    ...
    multiSort: true,
    ...
});
```

That will give you the ability to click multiple headers. If you want to sort programmatically, this should work:

```
$('#gridId')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'd0_key', true, 'asc')
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', 'd0_tot_key', true, 'asc');
```

There are other additional properties that may be of interest to you that go on the column model objects, such as `firstsortorder` (`"asc"`/`"desc"`) and `sortable` (`true`/`false`).

Also, it looks like there were some bug fixes in 4.5.1 and 4.5.4 for multi-sorting, so I would just go ahead and download the latest version.